# Android - How to swipe between activities like Snapchat?

Tags: android, swipe, snapchat

I've been looking for some way to change activities by swiping the finger , without using tabs. I want to animate the whole screen when the swipe starts, including the action bar and its icons. Just like the [Snapchat](https://www.snapchat.com/) works, you can go to the others screens just by swiping right or left. There's a lot of question about this but any one could help, I know it's possible because of Snapchat, how can I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: It is called a ViewPager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: @DroidBender is correct - and just to clarify you are swiping between fragments not activities. A view pager lets you load a bunch of fragments and then swipe the screen to move between them

Comment: Thanks. But I've already tried with fragments, and it would work fine except about the action bar, I want to move the action bar with the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `overridePendingTransition (int enterAnim, int exitAnim)` where you will pass animation resource identifiers.

As of `Jelly Bean` you can use `ActivityOptions` to perform transitions as you would do with `overridePendingTransition()` method. Or use `ActivityOptionsCompat`

Comment: Thank you, but how I use that with swipe?

Answer (score 0):

you can user fragment's viewPager along side with appropriate transformation , I guess fade is the right one, you can find plenty of transformation [here](https://github.com/ToxicBakery/ViewPagerTransforms)

> github.com/ToxicBakery/ViewPagerTransforms

.

Comment: It would be better if you quoted the most important parts of the link in case the linked page changes.